# Set GPO computer configuration with PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, group-policy

I want to set local users and groups in the computer configuration of my GPO with PowerShell.

Aim is to create and update the following structure.

[image]

Currently I'm using Powershell Version 4 on a Windows Server 2012 R2. 
The Group Policy Cmdlets Documentation from Technet was not very helpful.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

Is there any way to achieve this with PowerShell ?

Comment: Are you hoping to replace the GPO with a PowerShell startup script, or did you want to attach a PowerShell script to a GPO? Or are you trying to completely create the GPO using only PowerShell cmdlets? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As a side note, it would be worth upgrading to the Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5, which will upgrade this server to PowerShell 5 at the same time.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry for the late response. A couple of weeks ago I created a script to create and manage the GPO with PowerShell. There are no cmdlets for that. Even in version 5 no cmdlets exist for that task. So I create the "Groups.xml" in SYSVOL folder on the domain controller with PowerShell. It's a lot of code needed to manage the XML file. As soon as I have a reliable version, I will release it.

Answer (score 1):

To control the members of local groups, suggest you take a look at the Restricted Groups options within the Security branch.
[image]

Comment: Agreed. This, or Preferences.